# Error in Swift : (key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an error: Error: (key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'. Help me please to fix the issue, I tried different solutions, but unsuccessfully.

```
func getLastDayRatesData() -> NSDictionary? {
    if var rates = getRatesDataFromPlist() {
        if let lastUpdated = rates["last_updated"] as? NSDate{
            let ratesWithoutDate: NSMutableDictionary = rates as! NSMutableDictionary
            var sortedByDateRates = sorted(ratesWithoutDate) {($0.0 as! String) > ($1.0 as! String)}
            if let latestRates = sortedByDateRates.first {
                return latestRates // Error: (key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Paste more code? What is inside getRatesDataFromPlist()?

Comment: You try to sort a dictionary which results in an array of key-value tuples. You cannot sort dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you. I have found a solution.

Comment: Hi Stillfinder, welcome to the site and happy that you found a solution. You should probably edit the question with the solution, add an answer of your own or remove the question entirely. Help the community by explaining the issue or if not possible, then just remove the question rather than leave it cluttering the website (i.e. a question without a useful answer). If you found an answer on SO point a link to that solution and describe it. Don't leave a messy question with no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed your code to

```
func getLastDayRatesData() ->  (AnyObject, AnyObject)?
```

and everything works good.